# Почему утро "мудренее"?

Tags: этимология

Почему "утро вечера мудренее", а не "мудрее"? Ведь "мудрёный" означает "трудный для понимания, замысловатый", "непонятный". Или у поговорки изначально было другое значение, а не то, которые мы используем сейчас?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Или у поговорки изначально было другое значение, а не то, которые мы
>   используем сейчас?

Нет, другое значение было не у поговорки, а у слова "мудрёный". [В "Словаре русского языка XVIII в."](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/) слово мудрёный вообще не имеет негативных коннотаций, а значение, которое оно имеет в пословице, выделено отдельным пунктом:

> **Мудреный**.
>   ...
>   **2.** Прост. *Мудрый, умный*. Хитреѣ, мудренѣе, смысленѣе лисицы быти. ВЛ 483. Мудреных от меня не ждите вы словес, А в срок купить горазд и cѣно и овес. Длгрк. Соч. I 468. Как он был человѣк не гораздо
>   мудреный, то и высокоумие его не далеко простиралось. Зап. Блтв I 369.
>   | *В посл*. **Утро вечера мудренѣе**. Брсв Посл. 219. Так не к чему спѣшить;
>   **день ночи мудренѣе**. Дмтр. I 90.

Ещё один аргумент, пусть косвенный, но вполне убедительный, я считаю. Эта поговорка есть также в украинском языке: *ранок вечора мудріший* (встречается также *ранок за вечір мудріший* и др. аналогичные варианты [ранок — утро]). Слово "мудріший" означает "мудрее" и не имеет в украинском языке никаких отрицательных оттенков значения.

Comment: А можно ссылку нормальную на словарь? Впрочем, меня даже не битая ссылка смущает, а необходимость отсылки к XVIII веку единственно в поисках значения, которое и сейчас существует. И идет первым в БТС Кухнецова. Добро бы это как-то объясняло появление слова "мудренее" вместо синонимичного (по вашей логике) "мудрее"...

Comment: @behemothus Ссылку исправил, спасибо. В Кузнецова (в статье "мудрёный") нет приведенного в моём ответе просторечного значения (или укажите точнее, где посмотреть, если Вы видели). Согласен, что в наши дни немного странно видеть, что составители того словаря привели эту пословицу к просторечному значению слова "мудрёный", а не к основному. Но как раз в этом суть моего ответа.

Comment: Я имел в виду первое значение у Кузнецова. Но если вы настаиваете, что это другое значение, не буду спорить. Не потому, что нет аргументов, а потому, что нет сил. Я постараюсь найти современный словарь (а я его точно видел), где хитрый, мудреный и трудный (для понимания, осмысления - как в БТС) даются синонимами.

Answer (score 3):

Хороший вопрос. Плохо только то, что опять вопрос начинается с "почему", а на такие вопросы крайне редко удается дать ответ, который был бы адекватным одновременно и по форме, и по содержанию. На вопросы с "почему" надо отвечать "потому что...", а это заведомо невозможно, язык у нас такой и такие в нем пословицы-поговорки. Сложилось так.

Чтобы дать внятный ответ, я позволю себе переформулировать. ***Что означает в данной поговорке слово "мудренее" и какова его этимология?*** Строго говоря, абсолютного аргументированного ответа даже на такой вопрос у меня нет. Но есть версия.

Есть в русском языке такой глагол "мудрить", который сейчас используется в основном с негативной коннотацией (намудрил, перемудрил и проч.), но исходно он такого смысла не нес, обозначал всего лишь процесс мышления, изобретения чего-либо, поиска решения. Это исходное значение в полной мере проявляет себе в причастии "умудренный".

Так вот, слово **"мудреный"** вполне может трактоваться как **отглагольное прилагательное глагола "мудрить"** (собственно, другого-то ничего и не остается, альтернативной этимологии нет), а значение его следует сводить не к "мудрый", а скорее к ***"способный обдумывать"***. 
Другими словами, в поговорке речь идет не о "мудрости" утра, а о способности принять взвешенное решение.

В этой версии не все гладко. Во-первых, отгагольные прилагательные не так часто имеют продуктивные сравнительные формы, но это не абсолютный запрет.
А во-вторых (и это более серьезное возражение), у глагола "мудрить" в народной речи было еще одно, куда более распространенное в сравнении с предлагаемым (думать, решать), значение "шутить, насмехаться". И вот как это значение уживалось с предлагаемым в контексте поговорки, не совсем понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Утро вечера мудренее, трава соломы зеленее.

В словаре Даля есть глагол **мудренеть** , становиться мудреным, мудреть , опытом и наукою доходить до чего-то.
Чисто моё предположение, что именно от этого глагола с этим значением и произошла сравнительная форма , употребленная в пословице, утром легче принять решение ( отложить решение до утра).

Comment: Как вы себе предсавляете образование прилагательного (или страдательного причастия) от непереходного глагола?